# Uploading byte[] in BLOB mysql seems chopped up, why?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

Hi guys how're u doing:

Im trying to upload images via enctype="multipart/form-data" to mysql row and Im getting strange results:

**Java JSP to view the image:**

```
 <a href="viewevent?id=<%= viewevent.getId()%>">
    <img alt="" class="img-responsive image1" src="ViewImage?id=<%= viewevent.getId() %>">
 </a>
```

**Java ViewImage servlet method to view images:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    DataAccess bd = new DataAccess();
    bd.openConnection();
    ResultSet rs = bd.exQuery("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE id="+id , "SELECT");

    try{
        while(rs.next()){
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            System.out.println(rs.getBytes("foto"));
            response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("foto"));

            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("image/png");
            // Write image content to response.
            response.getOutputStream().write(rs.getBytes("foto"));
        }
        bd.closeConnection();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error cogiendo foto");
    }



}
```

**Java JSP to upload images:**

```
                    <form action="addevent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        ...
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="foto">Image</label>
                            <input name="foto" id="imagen" type=file accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">                                 
                        </div>                          
                       ...
                    </form>
```

**And addevent servlet code to upload the image:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
    ...
    Part foto = request.getPart("foto");
    ...
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) foto.getSize()];
    foto.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length);

    bd.exQuery("UPDATE eventos SET foto = '"+data+"' WHERE titulo='"+titulo+"';", "UPDATE");
    bd.closeConnection();
...

}
```

When i save BLOB files from MySQL as txt files i get following contents:

```
[B@2a83de12 
[B@3d00eeab
...
```

As u can see when I save them as txt I only get some characters... with this code Im not being able to upload images and view them on src. I dont know what Im doing wrong but this wont work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ResultSet rs = bd.exQuery("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE id="+id` <-- SQL injection waiting to happen...

Comment: @fge I know SQL injection could happen there but this isnt going to be put on production so I dont mind.

Comment: @RomanC i tried to replace it to data.toString() but I get the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bd.exQuery("UPDATE eventos SET foto = '"+data+"' WHERE titulo='"+titulo+"';", "UPDATE");
```

The problem is here. You are doing SQL string concatenation, which invokes `byte[].toString()`, which yields results like `[B@2a83de12`. You should be using a prepared statement with argument markers, and providing the BLOBs via arguments to the prepared statement:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE eventos SET foto = ? WHERE titulo=?");
ps.setObject(1, data);
ps.setObject(2, titulo);
int rowCount = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Moral: don't use SQL concatenation. Ever. All kinds of pitfalls lurk therein. 'Not for production' doesn't change that.